# Communication between interactive ocaml interpreter and another process

Tags: c, pipe, ocaml, fork, ipc

I need to load a *.ml file into the Ocaml toplevel (the interactive interpreter, when you type 'ocaml' in a shell) and then send an instruction from a Matlab process, get back the result of the instruction, send back another instruction, ...

I've made this C program. The parent process gets the Matlab's instruction from a named pipe, sends it to the child process (with ocaml running) and gets the response back so it can send it to Matlab.

But there is some kind of bug: when I send an instruction, I get back some weird characters, I send another instruction and then I receive the response of the first instruction...

(I didn't copy the perror() test to have less text)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void) {

    // Parent -> Child
    int pipe_in[2];
    // Child -> parent
    int pipe_out[2];

    /*
        pipe[0] = output
        pipe[1] = input
    */

    pipe(pipe_in);
    pipe(pipe_out);

    pid_t pid;
    if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
        // CHILD SIDE

        close(pipe_in[1]);
        close(pipe_out[0]);

        dup2(pipe_in[0], STDIN_FILENO);     
        dup2(pipe_out[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2(pipe_out[1], STDERR_FILENO);

        close(pipe_in[0]);
        close(pipe_out[1]);

        char *args[] = {"ocaml", NULL};
        execvp("ocaml", args);

        printf("FAIL\n");

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);     

    } else {
        // PARENT SIDE

        printf("[*] PID : %d\n", (int) pid);

        close(pipe_in[0]);
        close(pipe_out[1]);

        char cmd[1024];
        char feedback[1024];
        ssize_t cmd_read;
        ssize_t feedback_read = sizeof(feedback);

        while (1) {

            // Get the instruction from Matlab.
            printf("[>] ");
            int fifo_in = open("/tmp/pipe_in", O_RDONLY);
            cmd_read = read(fifo_in, cmd, sizeof(cmd));
            close(fifo_in);         
            printf("%s\n", cmd);

            // Send the instruction to the ocaml interpreter.
            write(pipe_in[1], cmd, cmd_read);

            // Read the response of the ocaml interpreter.
            while (feedback_read == sizeof(feedback)) {
                feedback_read = read(pipe_out[0], feedback, sizeof(feedback));
                printf("[-] %d\n", (int) feedback_read);
            }

            printf("[<] %s\n", feedback);

            // Send to Matlab the response.
            int fifo_out = open("/tmp/pipe_out", O_WRONLY);
            write(fifo_out, feedback, feedback_read);
            close(fifo_out);

            cmd_read = 0;
            feedback_read = sizeof(feedback);

        }

        close(pipe_in[1]);
        close(pipe_out[0]);
    }
}
```

---

I compile the code with `gcc -Wall -std=c99 -o tphr tphr.c`
I run the programm in one shell and in another :

```
> printf 'let x = 10;;\n' > /tmp/pipe_in

> cat /tmp/pipe_out
OCaml version 4.03.0

# %

> printf 'let y = 5;;\n' > /tmp/pipe_in

> cat /tmp/pipe_out
val x : int = 10
# %
```

---

How can I fix the result ?

Answer (score 0):

If, by "weird characters", you mean

> OCaml version 4.03.0

that is simply because this is what the OCaml toplevel prints out on startup. So you need to read this line when your own program starts up.

If you mean the `#` symbol, also known as the *prompt*, you can turn it off by running `ocaml -nopromt`.

Comment: Sorry, this wasn't clear, by weird character I don't speak about the header or the prompt. Each '%' characters replace escaped character like '^[[A', and other non-visible one. But even with weird character, why the program can't read all the response (the header and val x ...) of the first instruction ? The condition of the while isn't good ? It's because the child process never close his side of the pipe ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to run the interactive ocaml toplevel here for multiple reasons:

1. the toplevel parses the configfiles of the user and then loads different modules. This can change the available values, change behaviour, and make your matlab process get different results per user.
2. the output of the toplevel may change between versions making it difficult to parse and return the right reply to matlab

Did you know that you can call the toplevel from ocaml bytecode to interprete strings? I suggest dumping the C code and writing ocaml byte code to read from the pipe, interpret the command and reply with the result.

Comment: I need to load in memory a file and interpret all the instructions to interact with functions and variables defined without interpreting again the file. I need to call a function, get the result, call another function, get another result, ... Do you think I can do that with your technique ?

Comment: Sure. Ocaml can open a file, read it into a string and pass it to the interpreter. In bytecode that is. doesn't work in native code since that doesn't have an interpreter to call.